# How to create a loop using values from appSettings in my console application

Tags: c#, loops, app-config

Since I'm new in C# I need some help.

In my console application, in `App.config` I added a key which contains 2 paths(as seen below).

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myPath" value="D:\APPS\Sys\ARS\Db, C:\APPS\Sys\ARS\Lg" />
</appSettings>
```

What I would like to do is, to create a method which loops through these paths, search if the following files exist respectively for `D:\...: error.log` and for `C:\...: errtier0.log`.
Finally to return the full path with the file included, e.g. `D:\APPS\Sys\ARS\Db\error.log`.

Thank you in advance

What I did so far is,
In the beginning I created 2 different keys, one for each path, and I had 2 methods (see the one below) which were searching for each file in the key path.

```
public static string findRemedy()
{
    string myRemedyPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myRemedyPath"];
    DirectoryInfo remedyPath = new DirectoryInfo(myRemedyPath);
    foreach (var remedy in remedyPath.GetFiles("error.log"))
    {
        return remedy.Name;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Afterwards, I was parsing the value in another method in which I was adding the name of the file in the path

```
public static string findPath()
{        
    string fileRem = findRemedy();
    string Rpath = @"D:\APPS\Sys\ARS\Db\" + fileRem;
    return Rpath;
}
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i updated my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the setting in to a string, split it and try to open a file at each path. Return the first one that works

```
string appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myPath"];
string[] paths = appSetting.Split[','];
foreach(string path in paths){
   //Check if file exists by appending the file name to end of path 
   //and attempting to open the file
   //If successful return path, if not return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myPath"];

string[] parts = myPath.Split(',');
foreach (string part in parts)
{
   //do what you want
}
```